# jQuery to enable multiple background images to fade in and out

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to build a page with jQuery and the page will use several different large images as backgrounds to fade in and out.

How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should try doing this yourself first. If you run into a problem you can't fix while trying, feel free to [ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) **about that specific problem**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to re-invent the wheel. There are awesome plugins built on top of jQuery, feel free to utilize them according to your need. Here are some for your requirement https://www.sitepoint.com/responsive-fullscreen-background-image-plugins